# XSD for the XML file that Nunit uses

Tags: xsd, nunit

Where can I find the XSD for the XML file that Nunit uses ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the results file? See [Results.xsd](http://www.nunit.org/docs/2.2/files/Results.xsd) (note that it didn't display properly for me, in Chrome; you may have to view source, or download, to see it properly).

A transform file, and a sample results file, are in the [parent directory](http://www.nunit.org/docs/2.2/files). The files are also in the documentation package on the NUnit download page.

Comment: Since then an updated file is available in this directory: http://www.nunit.org/docs/2.6.3/files/